# Order By Hibernate no JSF

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, hibernate

Olá, boa tarde, sou iniciante nesse mundo web e estou precisando ordenar estabelecimentos por pontuação (os mais bem pontuados no inicio, LÓGICO)

O erro é `An Error Occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Tá aqui minha entidade, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda

```
public class Estabelecimento implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Integer id;
@Column
String nome;
String cnpj;
String cidade;
String bairro;
String rua;
String numero;
String telefone;
int pontos;
```

Aqui o código Bean

```
public List listaEstabelecimentosPontos(){
  listaEstabelecimentos =  estabelecimentoDao.ordenarPontos();
  return this.listaEstabelecimentos;
}
```

E aqui o xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="tabela" value="#{estabelecimentosBean.listaEstabelecimentosPontos()}">
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{tabela.id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="nome">
            <h:outputText value="#{tabela.nome}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="cnpj">
            <h:outputText value="#{tabela.cnpj}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="cidade">
            <h:outputText value="#{tabela.cidade}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="bairro">
            <h:outputText value="#{tabela.bairro}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="rua">
            <h:outputText value="#{tabela.rua}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="numero">
            <h:outputText value="#{tabela.numero}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="telefone">
            <h:outputText value="#{tabela.telefone}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="AÇÕES">
              <center>
              <p:commandButton value="Remover" action="#{estabelecimentosBean.removerEstabelecimento(tabela)}" />
              <p:commandButton value="Editar" action="#{estabelecimentosBean.atualizarEstabelecimento(tabela)}" />
              </center>
        </p:column>

     </p:dataTable>
  </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Log de error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.com.fastchoice.DAO.EstabelecimentoDAO.ordenarPontos(EstabelecimentoDAO.java:37)
at br.com.fastchoice.bean.EstabelecimentosBean.listaEstabelecimentosPontos(EstabelecimentosBean.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:183)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:759)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:806)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:788)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:281)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:243)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:85)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Classe DAO

```
public class EstabelecimentoDAO {

Session sessao;
Transaction trans;
List<Estabelecimento> list;

public List<Estabelecimento> getList() {
    sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    trans = sessao.beginTransaction();
    Criteria cri = sessao.createCriteria(Estabelecimento.class);
    this.list = cri.list();
    return list;

}

public List<Estabelecimento> ordenarPontos() {
    String jpql = "SELECT * FROM Estabelecimento estabelecimento ORDER BY estabelecimento.pontos DESC";
    return sessao.createQuery(jpql).getResultList();
}/**/


public void adicionarEstabelecimento(Estabelecimento es) {
    try {
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        trans = sessao.beginTransaction();

        Estabelecimento estabelecimento = new Estabelecimento();
        estabelecimento.setCnpj(es.getCnpj());
        estabelecimento.setNome(es.getNome());

        estabelecimento.setCidade(es.getCidade());
        estabelecimento.setBairro(es.getBairro());
        estabelecimento.setRua(es.getRua());
        estabelecimento.setNumero(es.getNumero());
        estabelecimento.setTelefone(es.getTelefone());
        estabelecimento.setPontos(es.getPontos());
        sessao.save(estabelecimento);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
}

public void removerEstabelecimento(Estabelecimento es) {

    try {
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        trans = sessao.beginTransaction();

        sessao.delete(es);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }

}

public void editarEstabelecimento(Estabelecimento es) {

    try {
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        trans = sessao.beginTransaction();

        sessao.update(es);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Você pode postar a sua query também?

Comment: Fiz na classe EstabelecimentoDAO, correto? http://pastebin.com/R3dsSwXW

Comment: David, você pode clicar em [edit] e adicionar essas informações na sua pergunta. Assim ficará bem visível para as outras que vierem tentar lhe ajudar. Também te recomendo fazer o [tour], ler [ask] e [como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](/help/mcve)

Comment: O pastebin também não é uma boa ideia. Muita gente tem acesso bloqueado à determinados sites. Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código nela.

Comment: Pronto, editado, me desculpem, sou novo nesse sistema de fórum

Comment: Tranquilo, o começo é meio confuso mesmo. Mas logo você vai conseguir usar o site tranquilamente. Sua pergunta ficou bem melhor agora, só pra ressaltar o [pt.so] não é um fórum.

Comment: Essa sua query é uma typedquery? O erro está falando que espera uma string, porém está sendo passado uma string e uma classe. Tente deixar apenas a string jpql, removendo a classe Estabelecimento.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, agora o erro é outro

Comment: Você pode colocar a pilha de erro, por favor? Uma linha apenas de log é insuficiente para melhor análise. Assim poderemos saber onde está ocorrendo o erro.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, aqui nesse trecho de código:

```
public List<Estabelecimento> ordenarPontos() {
    String jpql = "SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos ORDER BY pontos DESC";
    return sessao.createQuery(jpql).list();
}
```

você está fazendo uma busca com parâmetros de forma errada.

O correto seria:

```
public List<Estabelecimento> ordenarPontos() {
    sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    trans = sessao.beginTransaction();
    String jpql = "SELECT estabelecimento FROM Estabelecimento estabelecimento ORDER BY estabelecimento.pontos DESC";
    return sessao.createQuery(jpql).list();
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abs

Comment: Olá Weslley, estou usando Mysql e testei esse código acima, aparece uma mensagem de erro

Error Code: 1146. Table 'fastchoice.estabelecimento' doesn't exist

Já com q estou usando ele aparece os estabelecimentos por ordem decrescente normalmente

Comment: Existe uma diferença entre o código SQL e o JPQL @DavidFilipe. Se você cria queries dentro do seu código utilizando o `hibernate`, você deve utilizar JPQL, não SQL. Tente colocar o método que eu coloquei na minha resposta no seu código e execute o seu projeto. Aguardo o seu feedback.

Comment: Continua o erro java.lang.NullPointerException, posso te passar o projeto no github? Creio que seria melhor para melhor análise

Comment: Veja a minha edição. Abs

Comment: o getResultList está dando erro

cannot find symbol

Comment: Por favor, edite a sua pergunta postando o código que contém a classe do objeto `sessao` no seu código.

Comment: Pronto, editei, não conseguir postar os imports

Comment: Tudo bem. Editei novamente a resposta. Verifique se da forma que está agora, o seu problema é resolvido. Abs

Comment: Agora é outro erro

An Error Occurred:

unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM br.com.fastchoice.entity.Estabelecimento estabelecimento ORDER BY estabelecimento.pontos DESC]

kkk tá complicado

Comment: Editei novamente a resposta. PS: Tô sem IDE aqui pra testar, tô na casa de um amigo e peguei o PC dele emprestado pra te ajudar.

Comment: FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOI, meu DEUS, muito obrigado cara, mas muito mesmo, esse pouco do seu tempo que vc parou pra me ajudar, putz vc n tem noção do quanto eu já quebrei a cabeça com ''essa besteira'' muito obrigado mesmo cara, faz 4 dias que eu falei que estava precisando de ajuda no projeto e professor só visualiza e não responde, quer que vc implemente algo em que além de não ensinar, não está te tirando as dúvidas, muito obrigado mesmo cara.

Comment: Por nada @DavidFilipe. Continue estudando sobre `hibernate`, é um framework muito importante nos projetos atuais. Marque a resposta como correta, caso alguém venha a ter um problema parecido com o seu.

Comment: Outra coisa Weslley, se não for abusar da sua boa vontade, estou em uma situação muito complicada em que estou programando sozinho em um grupo de 5 pessoas, na próxima entrega preciso fazer algumas funcionalidades do sistema, você poderia me indicar onde procurar? Não precisa codificar pra mim, apenas me indicar onde procurar já seria de muito ajuda.

Comment: Tá aqui as funcionalidades

http://pastebin.com/rv9NkzS0

Comment: Me mande seu e-mail para que possamos discutir sobre isso a noite. Agora tô de saída pro trabalho.

Comment: filipe.r13@live.com. Me manda algo que eu entro em contato, mesmo assim muito obrigado cara, bom trabalho.